# Mongoose validation err: Invalid schema configuration

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Trying to model a relationship between collections by embedding documents
but when validating in the schema and setting "required" to True, here comes the err

once I comment the required in genre object in movies schema the problem is solved
but I want the validation

```
const Movie = mongoose.model(
  'Movies',
  new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 255
    },
    numberInStock: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 255
    },
    dailyRentalRate: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 255
    },
    genre: genreSchema
    required: true
  })
);

const genreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50
  }
});
```

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type at path `required`

Comment: `required: true` looks like a field but that is the reason you are getting invalid schema configuration error.

Answer (score 5):

you can use **references** and use **populate** when fetching

```
genre: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'genreSchema',
        required: true
    }],
```

Refer: [Model Referenced one to Many Relationship between documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) 
for better schema design

Comment: @Omid Then you should write a logic to validate it. I do not think so you can make an embedded document as required one. If you go with references then it is possible

Comment: I do not think so it works, But give it a try ```genre: {
        genreSchema: genreSchema,
        required: true
    }```

Comment: Yes, I agree. you can use references and use populate when fetching

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the message next to true.
For example-->  required: [true, "Title required"]

Answer (score 2):

Remove `required: true` and Follow this from the official [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). Note the version of mongoose used.
I got the same error and solved it. My mistake was making the subdocument a model instead of keeping it as a schema

```
const childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

const parentSchema = new Schema({
  // Array of subdocuments
  children: [childSchema],
  // Single nested subdocuments. Caveat: single nested subdocs only work
  // in mongoose >= 4.2.0
  child: childSchema
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please share full code.

Maybe the main reason is that u not used

```
const Movie = mongoose.model(
  'Movies',
  new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 255
    },
    numberInStock: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 255
    },
    dailyRentalRate: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 255
    },
    genre: {
        ref: 'SchemaName',
        required: true
    },
  })
);
```

You can do this like this.

Answer (score 1):

because you forgot to put "," here:

```
genre: genreSchema <<<here
required: true
```

should be:

```
genre: genreSchema,
required: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Export the genre model as
`exports.genreSchema = genreSchema`

Then in `movies.js` file import the model as
`import { genreSchema } from './genre.model'`

Try doing this the error will not come.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing "required:true" problem

Don't pass the function
`new mongoose.Schema({})`. Instead of this you just have to make
`const Schema = mongoose.Schema;`
then use `Schema({})`.

It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve it.

```
import { Schema, model, Model } from 'mongoose';

    const obj1Scheema:Schema = new Schema({
        genre:{type:genreSchema.schema, ... rest of the presets} 
        GenreArr: {type:[genreSchema.schema], ... rest of the presets}
    })

    //genre schema:
    const genreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
         name: {
         type: String,
         required: true,
         minlength: 5,
         maxlength: 50
     }
   });

/*
        genre:{ ... genre fields} 
        GenreArr:[{... genre fields}]

*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Your forget to put `","` in end of  `genre:genreSchema` or rewrite your code like

```js
genre: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'genreSchema',
        required: true
    }],
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.